# as3 movieclip antialias

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I kept a bitmap inside a movieClip, bitmap has been set to be smoothing. but when I changed the scale of this movieclip, it still got pixelated. Do we have the way to avoid. it is really painful.

Comment: do you need it in a MovieClip?

Comment: Just a side note: if you upscale (make it bigger) it will always be pixelated.

Answer (score 1):

**When you scale bitmaps, quality gets lost, always.**

- Always snap x and y positions to full pixels.
- `stage.quality = "best"` gives you better anti-alliasing (bicubic), but it cost more CPU.
- Try to find out what the maximum scale of the image could be. Then make the image at that size.
- Most people dont't see its not that smooth, just make the game runs smooth and fun. so relax about it.